# Javascript - add a character to existing string in specific field of web page as a client

Tags: javascript

Need modification of existing code below, which currently copying from that field, to instead keep the string of characters that is already there AND add a character to the beginning of that string, i.e. result should be "X ABC", where X is added character and ABC existing string.  I am using that web page as a client.

```js
javascript:(function() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");

    tempAlert("COPIED SUBJECT", 500);
    function tempAlert(msg, duration) {
        var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.setAttribute("style","position:absolute;top:1%;left:35%;background-color:white;");
        el.innerHTML = msg;
        document.body.appendChild(el);

        setTimeout(function(){
                el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
            }, duration
        );
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to modify your code because it's not really relevant to the question at hand.

Here's how you can combine two strings:

Assuming your variable `msg` is `abc`

```
let prefix = 'X';
El.innerHTML = `${prefix} ${msg}`;
```

Should result in `X abc`

Comment: Can you maybe modify this version, I'm trying to make a bookmarklet? javascript:(function() {var copyText = document.getElementById("mergeFields-input-text");copyText.innerHTML = "-" + copyText.innerHTML();})();

Comment: Nah, maybe if it was a working copy in plunkr or something. Try to use my exerpt